# Ctrl + Alt + V: Disable auto-generation of the keyword "final"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

It was not like this in version 1.5, but now that I updated my Android Studio to 2.1.1 whenever I generate a local variable with the Ctrl + Alt + V shortcut, the variable is generated with the keyword "final".

For example, let's say I have the following statements:

```
Object o = new Object();
o.toString();
```

Let's highlight the second line and press Ctrl + Alt + V and voila:

```
final String s = o.toString();
// ^ I'm talking about this.
```

How do I disable the auto-generaion of the keyword "final"?

This auto-insertion of final is highly annoying as I use this shortcut like every other minute and I have to delete the keyword because most of the time I don't need the variable to be final and would not like to keep my code unnecessarily wordy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you want to turn it off since it is good practice.

Here is how you can do that:
[image: settings]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The primary reason I'd refrain from applying `final` on loocal variables by dfault is, as I already said, it increases verbosity and is distracting. The secondary reason is that most of the time the variables need not be final, although they'd better be. I recognise benefits of marking variables final and I actually think it could've been better if variables were final by default and can be optionally be non-final but too bad they aren't.